# How to get the labels for the edges that make up a path in a digraph?

Tags: erlang

I have a digraph and a list of connected vertices (i.e., a path in the graph). Assuming that each edge in the graph has a label, how can I retrieve the labels for the edges in the path?

Having looked at the [digraph docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html), I don't know how I can accomplish what I need to do. *digraph:edge/2* seems like the only function that returns the label of an edge, but I need to have that edge in the first place... Which I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`digraph:edges/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html#edges-1) to get a list of all edges in the graph, then call [`digraph:edge/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html#edge-2) on each edge to obtain its `{Edge, Vertex1, Vertex2, Label}` tuple. For example, the list comprehension below would return a list of such tuples for graph `G`:

```
[digraph(G,E) || E <- digraph:edges(G)]
```